# Can MikroTik block certain YouTube channels?

Tags: mikrotik

I want to block some adult content from YouTube.

Can MikroTik routers block certain Youtube Channels? Or certain content from YouTube?

Comment: support@mikrotik.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes and no. You can block specific videos from YouTube, but as far as I know, not a certain YouTube channel due the format of YouTube URLs.

Through RouterOS, you can accomplish this using one of these two methods:

1) You can create Layer 7 Protocol specifications in the Firewall section, and then firewall rules to block them;

2) You can enable RouterOS built-in web-proxy and block them there.

Hope that helps.

Best regards.

Comment: YouTube uses TLS. You cannot block specific content (URLs) using L7 filters or the built-in web proxy. The most you can do is block the domain name using those methods.